Load Vue.js component async
I'm working in a legacy project where we have both Vue 3 (migrated from Vue2) and jQuery.
I have wrapped some form fields within Vue components, like this:
Outlet.vue
<template>
  <div :class="`form-group outlet-field step-${step}`">
    <label class="label-name">
      {{ label }}
      <tooltip :required="required" :help="help" />
    </label>
    <select
      :name="name"
      :required="required"
      :disabled="isSelectDisabled"
      @change="onSelectionChange"
    >
      <option
        v-for="choice in filteredChoices"
        :value="choice.value"
        :key="choice.value"
      >
        {{ choice.label }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "Outlet",
  props: ["id", "name", "label", "choices", "required", "step", "help"],
  data() {
    return {
      filteredChoices: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('mounted');
  },
  methods: {
      // Some methods here
  },
};
</script>


I have few more similar components: Zip.vue, Datepicker.vue, etc.
The components are working fine when imported and loaded from the beginning, but I encountered problems when I render an entire form from the server async.
The request of my front-end app starts in form.js:
const formWrapper = $('#ajax-form-wrapper');
formWrapper.hide();
$.ajax({
    url: 'url-to-server',
    success: function (response) {
        formWrapper.html(response.form);
        formWrapper.show();
        // Load Vue components that are included within response.form markup
    }
});

Basically, server responds with form key and its value is an entire form with different fields (regular HTML fields and Vue components as fields).
Ex.
'form' => '<div>
    <input type="text">
    <select>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
    </select>
    <zip></zip>
    <outlet></outlet>
   ...
</div>


At the moment, I can see only the regular form fields from the entire fields, while the Vue components are not rendered, but only stored in DOM with their original Vue name (<outlet step="1" other-custom-props="test">
The main Vue file which initializes Vue, is in another file: app.js, but I don't think this is relevant.
Important. These form is rendered in a modal, so that's why I want to lazy-load these fields/Vue components only when needed. Therefore, I probably need to destroy these components once the modal is closed, right?
I read about using defineAsyncComponent method, but still, the Vue components are not being rendered and also don't get any error.
Any hints are welcome. Thanks

Lots of things are listed here, maybe try to await until the DOM is mounted, then nextTick, then remove any lazy-loading then you could debug it more easily. Think about the performance part later on.

It's unclear what exactly your case looks like. How is form.js related to app.js? "Load Vue components" - what does happen here? Since the rendering of "form" template is asynchronous and isn't in a direct of the main app, may need a sub-app for it to be rendered, which is generally a hack, like this is done https://github.com/pearofducks/mount-vue-component/blob/master/index.js . A proper solution potentially requires to incorporate the logic from form.js into defineAsyncComponent, so you'd return a synthetic comp with a template made from scratch. Consider providing a minimal demo to fix it

" I probably need to destroy these components once the modal is closed" - yes, with a sub-app you need to take care of this. If you use defineAsyncComponent instead of a sub-app, you can use a teleport for a modal in order for Vue to handle this for you
